# Is there an interesting generalization of Vaserstein's argument for Quillen-Suslin?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

One way to see that the algebraic vector bundles on an affine space over a field are trivial is to note that algebraic K-theory is $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant under a smoothness assumption. Another way was provided by Vaserstein. I wonder if the latter generalizes in any interesting way (within motivic homotopy theory or in some other settting).

Comment: The triviality of algebraic K-theory is not enough for Quillen-Suslin: it only proves that vector bundles on affine spaces are stably trivial, not trivial. Indeed the Bass-Quillen conjecture is still open

Comment: @DenisNardin On the other hand, the proof in Lang's Algebra deduces Quillen-Suslin from the stably free result and the fact that stably free modules over a commutative ring satisfying unimodular extension property are necessarily free. I don't know whether there are modern points of view of this step.